# Replace first instance of matching text on every line in a txt file

Tags: bash, macos, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a .txt file and I want to replace the first occurrence of a matching string on every line.

So, for example, here's what's inside foo.txt:

```
838dbc65cd79e16cf09f90abb928e3f3d0ea2d775cf8edc8acaabde6d393bc76  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/legos.png
415ccf1e05fb5985d2f719deabec7bb5d22aeaac7b82cca885010b12d483d997  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/folder/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/another folder/Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/fedora linux.7z
f3d0ea2d775cf8edc1ddbd76e2562d3e4a2e281fe2aeb1333ef99536d1a180ee  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/manuals/dryer.pdf
\ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\{2}:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% [meowzers] (1)~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
\9c993445f7f6216b4fc7d35aef47afa16f4f831f2510b7fddd1e42c4cafb518c  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\:`!CAT      MEOW!!![hey]{15}(hello)@$%&^*(#@@*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
```

I want to replace `Documents - Part 1` with `Documents - Part 1 BU`, **but** only the first occurrence on every line.

So, it would look like this in the end:

```
838dbc65cd79e16cf09f90abb928e3f3d0ea2d775cf8edc8acaabde6d393bc76  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/legos.png
415ccf1e05fb5985d2f719deabec7bb5d22aeaac7b82cca885010b12d483d997  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/folder/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/another folder/Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/fedora linux.7z
f3d0ea2d775cf8edc1ddbd76e2562d3e4a2e281fe2aeb1333ef99536d1a180ee  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/manuals/dryer.pdf
\ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\{2}:`!*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% [meowzers] (1)~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
\9c993445f7f6216b4fc7d35aef47afa16f4f831f2510b7fddd1e42c4cafb518c  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU/Test Hash Folder/#;."'&,\\:`!CAT      MEOW!!![hey]{15}(hello)@$%&^*(#@@*?$(){}[]<>|-=+% ~^^.$[E-frLOL[MAY[]{}()?<NUL>
```

I tried this:

```
cat foo.txt | grep "^.[\]{64}  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/" | sed "  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1 BU"`
```

but it didn't work. How can I fix this?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release, grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: `grep "^.[\]{64}  `: you are looking for 1 character followed by 64 '\' and 2 spaces at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed 's/Documents - Part 1/Documents - Part 1 BU/'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** `awk` solution.

```
awk '{sub("Documents - Part 1","Documents - Part 1 BU")} 1'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Use `sed -i` option in above code in case you want to save output into Input_file itself and append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to 2nd solution for doing the same.